# Shell decimal to hexadecimal

Tags: shell, hex, decimal

How can I print 55 as hexadecimal with echo from decimal number?

```
#equivalent to:
printf "%x" 55

#like this:
dec=55
hex=$(([##16]dec))

echo $[0xAA]
```

I searched a lot but did not find any echo snippets for the calculation from decimal to hexadecimal.

Comment: I don't think you can change the base for the output in an arithmetic context, and `printf` seems to be the perfect tool for what you're asking. What prevents you from using it?

Comment: `$[]` is a deprecated, undocument form of `$(())`. I'd suggest you stop using it.

Comment: `echo` does not support outputting a number in a different base.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I print 55 as hexadecimal with echo from decimal number?

It is not possible, `echo` as the name implies, echos what you give to it, it does no conversion.

> like this:

Yes, you can write a utility to convert a decimal number into hexadecimal number in shell. There is no such builtin conversion.

Converting a number to hex, or any other base, is relatively easy. For example in Bash:

```
hex() {
     local out="" dict=($(seq 0 9) a b c e d f)
     while (($1)); do
          out=${dict[$1 % 16]}$out
          set -- $(($1 / 16))
     done
     echo $out
}
hex 55
```

Conceptually same code, in sh:

```
hex () {
  out=""
  while [ $1 -ne 0 ]; do
     c=$(($1 % 16))
     case $c in
        10) c=a ;;   11) c=b ;;   12) c=c ;;
        13) c=d ;;   14) c=e ;;   15) c=f ;;
     esac
     out=$c$out
     set -- $(($1 / 16))
  done
  echo $out
}
hex 55
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> #!/bin/sh
>
> OUTPUT=`echo $1 |dc -e "16o?p"`
>
> echo $OUTPUT

and i have:

> user@raspberrypi:~ $ ./convert.sh 999
>
> 3E7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).